# Send DevExterme LoadOptions to aspnetzero

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular, aspnetzero

As mentioned in following document

[Developing-Step-By-Step-Angular-DevExtreme-Using-GetPeople-Method-from-Angular](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Developing-Step-By-Step-Angular-DevExtreme-Using-GetPeople-Method-from-Angular)

```cs
 this.dataSource = new CustomStore({
            key: "id",
            load: (loadOptions) => {
                return this._personService.getPeople("").toPromise();
            }
        });
```

the getPeople("") has no parameter. when I change it to getPeople(loadOptions) then I get null reference
in DataSourceLoadOptions in Back-End.
While testing I just ignored the generated proxy and sent it by http and now it works.

Is there something that I should do?

Answer (score 0):

So, I am not an angular expert by any stretch.  But I did find this code located here:

[DevExtreme ASP.NET Zero Integration](https://medium.com/volosoft/devextreme-asp-net-zero-integration-444ea26d0fc5)

in the Angular section, they had this code:

```
this.dataSource.store = new CustomStore({
        load(loadOptions: any) {
            var maxResultCount = loadOptions.take || 10;
            var skipCount = loadOptions.skip || 0;
            var sorting = '';

            if (loadOptions.sort) {
                sorting = loadOptions.sort[0].selector;
                if (loadOptions.sort[0].desc) {
                    sorting += ' desc';
                } else {
                    sorting += ' asc';
                }
            }

            return self._auditLogService.getAuditLogs(
                self.startDate,
                self.endDate,
                self.username,
                self.serviceName,
                self.methodName,
```

..........

Maybe this would help.

Good luck.  Let us know how you resolved it!

--Dave